# Why globals() doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, global

I am new to python and I wanted to simply change variables by using globals() but for some reason I keep getting same outpu (1, 2 ,3 instead a, b, c). What is wrong here?

```
cwp = "01"
aw_sg = "01"

a01 = 1
a02 = 2
a03 = 3

p01g01a01 = "a"
p01g01a02 = "b"
p01g01a03 = "c"

print a01, a02, a03


def load_db(a01, a02, a03, cwp, aw_sg):

    a01 = globals()["p%sg%sa01" % (cwp, aw_sg)]
    a02 = globals()["p%sg%sa02" % (cwp, aw_sg)]
    a03 = globals()["p%sg%sa03" % (cwp, aw_sg)]

    return a01, a02, a03

load_db(a01, a02, a03, cwp, aw_sg)

print a01, a02, a03
```

Comment: You do not actually store the return value of `load_db` anywhere, and since you have not marked a01, a02, and a03 as `global` inside `load_db`, the global-scope a01/etc are not being overwritten. (I assume you're asking this for purely academic reasons and not actually using `globals()` willy nilly like this.)

Comment: You’re assigning to local variables called `a01`, `a02`, and `a03` inside `load_db`. That doesn’t change the global variables. Use the return value, e.g. `print load_db(a01, a02, a03, cwp, aw_sg)`. Using real variable names is also a good idea, and not using `globals()` is an even better idea.

Comment: @ senshin yup I use this example to just understand how this works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `globals()` function to access global variables, but you have assigned them to local variables inside the function, and it doesn't change the global variables. If you want to change the global variables you can reassign the returned values by function to global variables.

```
a01, a02, a03 = load_db(a01, a02, a03, cwp, aw_sg)
print a01, a02, a03
```